# Github compare view for a specific path only?

Tags: github

I can view the changes between 2 commits with a url like this

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/compare/0e2f8f9...250fd80

But I'm interested in showing only the changes that affect a certain path like "src/css" for example. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

```
git diff commit1 commit2 folder_path
```

Comment: This answers how to do it in `git`, not in Github.
The reason for doing it in Github might be that one wants to share the link to the compare view of two subfolders.